# How can i get the highest integer from a list string

Tags: c#, list, integer, max

I have a video clip which contains a bunch of Meta data (Mostly single line of strings), which in turn are linked to a specific frame. I managed to separate the speed data from each line of the Meta data and store it with in another list `lc4_highest_speed_2`

```
     for (int h = 0; h < lc4_file_calculations.Count; h++)
                    {
     string hold_variable = lc4_file_calculations[h].Replace("-", ",");
     var mySplitResult2 = hold_variable.Split(',');
                            var speed = mySplitResult2[mySplitResult2.Length - 45];
                             lc4_highest_speed.Add(speed + ":" + h);
    }

for (int f = 0; f < lc4_highest_speed.Count; f++)
                {
 string hoe3 = lc4_highest_speed[f];
                    var mySplitResult3 = hoe3.Split(':');
                    var speed2 = mySplitResult3[mySplitResult3.Length - 2];
                    var speed3 = mySplitResult3[mySplitResult3.Length - 1];
                    string speed_test = speed2.ToString();
                        lc4_highest_speed_2.Add(speed2 + " - " + speed3);
}
```

The new list holds data like this `012 - 82` the first part before the `-` is the speed and the other is the index number related to value from another string. I have tried things like concat, however it hasn’t worked. What would be the best way to get the highest speed the element before the - while also keeping the relation of the index number the number after the -.

Thank you

Comment: Which entry in this list would you consider the "highest speed"?

Comment: Do you mean that the sort order is "by speed then by index"? So in your example, the highest will be "013 - 106"?

Comment: why do you create an object, for example, a  class car with properties id and max speed?
var car= lc4_highest_speed_2.OrderByDescending(item => item.Speed).First();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution in O(n) time complexity return the higher speed value with its high index value.

```
int highestSpeed = 0;
int indexNumber = 0;

foreach (var item in lc4_highest_speed_2)
{
   var values = item.Split('-');
   if (values?.Count() == 2)
   {
       int.TryParse(values[0], out int parsedValue);
       if (parsedValue > highestSpeed)
       {
           highestSpeed = parsedValue;
           int.TryParse(values[1], out indexNumber);
           continue;
       }

       int.TryParse(values[1], out int parsedIndex);
       if (highestSpeed == parsedValue && parsedIndex > indexNumber) indexNumber = parsedIndex;
   }
}
```

Comment: Faster than the linq solution. Could be made a very little better without checking for >= and adding a separate check for indexNumber. But it is already good as  it is now.

Comment: Has a bug though: Consider [ "12 - 500", "13 - 100" ] will result in highestSpeed = 13, indexNumber = 500

Comment: Yes it should reset the indexNumber to zero when the highestSpeed changes, but then there is a need for a different approach at the logic in the if  condition

Comment: @Fildor Yes, that is a bug. I have updated the answer

Comment: Why `values?.Count() == 2`? `values` is `string[]`. Use less `var` statements and `values.Length == 2` instead. And why are you `null`-checking here? Why `TryParse` if you're not checking if it returned `true` or `false`. It may cause `default(int)` to be returned and you'll get an unexpected behavior. `item.Split('-')` - did you test it? `string.Split` doesn't accept `char` as argument.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me figure out what i was doing wrong and to how to go about it

Answer (score 3):

Try following :

```
           string[] input = {
                                 "012 - 82",
                                 "012 - 83",
                                 "012 - 84",
                                 "012 - 85",
                                 "012 - 86",
                                 "012 - 87",
                                 "13 - 102",
                                 "13 - 103",
                                 "13 - 104",
                                 "13 - 105",
                                 "13 - 106"
                             };

            var output = input
                .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '-' }))
                .Select(x => new { speed = int.Parse(x.First()), index = int.Parse(x.Last()) })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.speed)
                .GroupBy(x => x.speed)
                .First()
                .ToList();
```

Comment: This is identifies the _group_ of entries with the highest speed. Not sure if the OP wants just one entry (IE when the speed is equal get the highest index)

Comment: That's doing an O(N(LogN)) sort to accomplish an O(N) operation though.

Comment: Yes but you then get First() so it is not doing a full sort.

Comment: @jdweng Ah yes, that's an optimisation in .Net Core. In .Net Framework 4.8, that will be O(N(Log(N)), but in .Net Core 3.1 it's O(N) (if you use .First())

Comment: Note that the output of this is `013 - 102` - but it's not clear if the OP wants the output to be `013 - 106` (they haven't answered the query on this point yet, so don't know if this is right or wrong yet)

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage a tuple to do this. Tuples automatically define an ordering based on their members that implement `IComparable<T>`. (Comparison is done in the order that the tuple's members are declared.)

Since an `int` implements `IComparable<T>` if we construct a tuple with the first element being the integer speed and the second the integer index, then the comparison operation generated for the tuple will be exactly what you need.

Thus you can solve this with a Linq expression that splits each row into the speed and index strings, parses those strings into ints and creates a tuple for each pair of speed and index. Then you can find the biggest using `IEnumerable.Max()`:

```
var max = lc4_highest_speed_2.Select(item =>
{
    var elements = item.Split("-");
    return (speed: int.Parse(elements[0].Trim()), index: int.Parse(elements[1].Trim()));
}).Max();
```

Note that `max` is a tuple with an int first element called `speed` and an int second element called `index`.

[Try it on .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bU3l1N)

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the speed value in the list of integer where you can find the mx value and using its index you then can find the relation between the speed and index value.

For the reference, I have created the small program. Hope you will understand

```
    using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;

     class HelloWorld {
     static void Main() {
      
      List<string> data = new List<string>();
      List<int> intdata = new List<int>();
      data.Add("012 - 82");
      data.Add("013 - 102");
      for(int i=0;i<data.Count;i++){
         intdata.Add(Int16.Parse(data[i].Substring(0,data[i].IndexOf("-"))));
      }
    Console.WriteLine(intdata.Max());
    }
  }
```

Comment: _"... however also keep the relation of the index number (after the -)"_ - OP

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
var maxSpeed = lc4.Max(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(' ')[0]));
var maxLine = lc4.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith($"{maxSpeed} "));
var maxIndex = Convert.ToInt32(maxLine.Split('-')[1].Substring(1));
```

or if you want all indices:

```
var maxSpeed = lc4.Max(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(' ')[0]));
var maxLines = lc4.Where(x => x.StartsWith($"{maxSpeed} "));
var maxIndexes = maxLines.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('-')[1].Substring(1)));
```